# Google Cloud Datastore (not Appengine): How to set a Java collection in an Entity

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I'm using a **non** AppEngine Google Cloud Datastore Java API. I store entities from outside the Google Cloud environment.

My Gradle dependency is:

`compile('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-datastore:0.8.0-beta')`

I have a List in an entity that I'd like to set in the Entity but there is no method to set a collection. Currently I'm setting values as follows:

```
/**
 * It returns a Google Datastore Entity from a DTO Entity
 * @param usersKey The Key to use to build the entity
 * @param user The Users entity containing the data to persist
 * @return A Google Datastore Entity from a DTO Entity
 */
public static Entity fromDtoToGoogleEntity(Key usersKey, User user) {

    Entity.Builder builder = Entity.newBuilder(usersKey);
    builder.set(User.FIRST_NAME, user.getFirstName());
    builder.set(User.LAST_NAME, user.getLastName());
    builder.set(User.PASSWORD, user.getPassword());
    builder.set(User.EMAIL, user.getEmail());
    builder.set(User.STRIPE_USER_ID, user.getStripeUserId());
    builder.set(User.COUNTRY, user.getCountry());
    builder.set(User.DESCRIPTION, user.getDescription());
    builder.set(User.USERNAME, user.getUsername());
    builder.set(User.ENABLED, user.isEnabled());       

    return builder.build();

}
```

There is no method such as:

```
builder.set(User.USER_ROLES, user.getUserRoles());//userRoles is a List<String>
```

Can anybody suggest a way? The only way so far is to have a comma separated String representation and convert from Collection to comma separated String and vice versa.

Thanks in advance.

M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of the below methods (http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.8.0/apidocs/com/google/cloud/datastore/BaseEntity.Builder.html) -

```
set(String name, List<? extends Value<?>> values)
set(String name, String first, String second, String... others)
```

See also the `ListValue` and `ListValue.Builder`.

The first one - you just create a list of `Value` objects (e.g. `StringValue`) and assign the list to a property on the entity. In essence, convert your `List<String>` to `List<StringValue>`.

The second one is a simpler variation with `String` var args, where you can pass your two or more Strings.

You may also consider using an ORM framework like Catatumbo (http://catatumbo.io) which takes care of the mapping of your model objects.

Disclosure: I'm the author of Catatumbo.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try it as soon as I've fixed few other problems :-)

Comment: Thank you, I've applied the first tip and it worked.